# Stubhub like map in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image of a floor plan.  Best way to think if it is a hotel floor plan.
(Similar to how stubhub does their ticket maps)
I want the user to select rooms. Instead of slicing each room in Photoshop, is there a way to split up the image in HTML5 canvas or Javascript.  Would like to avoid flash.

Is this even possible?!

Thanks for the responses!

example:
http://adamsaewitz.com/housing/housing.html

(top left rooms, hover)

Comment: Are rooms always rectangular and aligned with the screen grid? (Or, could the mouse detection for them be forced to be such?)

Comment: They are basically all rectangular enough that it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an image map ( http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp ) or if you know the coordinates of each room  you could have it stored in an array somewhere then when someone clicks the image find out if that click was in a room then do what you need.

here is an example of finding the coordinates of a click in an image http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/

Comment: That sounds pretty good actually! Are there any applications that would aid in the creation of this?  This seems to be one time that automated would be better than manual.